# Inbound NAT rules on Load balancer in Azure ARM, how to specify RANGE of ports?

Tags: azure, ftp, nat, azure-virtual-network, azure-resource-manager

In Azure, we are using a load balance to forward ports to our VMs using the Inbound NAT rules. We are trying to setup port forwarding for passive FTP ports, and so we need at least 100 ports to be forwarded. In the Image below, the NAT rules appear to only allow your to forward one port at a time. Is it possible to forward a range of ports? e.g. 60000-62000

[image: Inbound NAT rules in Azure ARM]

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the Image below, the NAT rules appear to only allow your to forward
>   one port at a time. Is it possible to forward a range of ports?

Port range is currently **not** supported.
As a workaround, we can use **PowerShell** to **update** this load balancer, and add multiple NAT rules to it.

```
$slb = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name NRPLB -ResourceGroupName NRP-RG
$slb | Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -Name ftp1 -FrontendIpConfiguration $slb.FrontendIpConfigurations[0] -FrontendPort 60000  -BackendPort 60000 -Protocol Tcp
$slb | Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -Name ftp2 -FrontendIpConfiguration $slb.FrontendIpConfigurations[0] -FrontendPort 60001  -BackendPort 60001 -Protocol Tcp
.
.
.
.
$slb | Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerInboundNatRuleConfig -Name ftp50 -FrontendIpConfiguration $slb.FrontendIpConfigurations[0] -FrontendPort 60050  -BackendPort 60050 -Protocol Tcp
$slb | Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer  #save the new configure
```

The current limit of load balancing rules is **150**, we can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits).[image]